# Append shell command to CFLAGS

Tags: gcc, makefile

I would like to append this string to the CFLAGS without modifying the makefile itself:

```
-frandom-seed=$(shell md5sum $< | sed 's/\(.*\) .*/\1/')
```

Simply appending to the CFLAGS variable before running make doesn't work, since it can't be evaluated at that moment.

Is there a way do it without modifying the makefile?

Comment: How does the makefile define (and use) the `CFLAGS` variable?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

For this option, you will have to be able to modify your Makefile once. Change the line  in your Makefile that modifies or sets `CFLAGS` to `override CFLAGS+=<current flags already being set in CFLAGS>`. So, if you currently have `CFLAGS=-std=c99` in your Makefile, change that to `override CFLAGS+=-std=c99`

Then, say you wanted to add `-g` for compilation, simply call make like so:

```
make CFLAGS=-g
```

This will prepend `-g` to -std=c99.

See the [override directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive) for more info.

**Option 2:**

**This is possible using the -e option passed when running make.**

> -e gives variables taken from the environment precedence over variables from makefiles.

For example, take the following Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-std=c++11
echoCFLAGS:
    @echo $(CFLAGS)
```

If you want to override CFLAGS with something else(-std=c99), then simply:

```
bash -c "export CFLAGS=-std=c++99"
make -e echoCFLAGS
```

> This outputs "-std=c99"

**Issues with Option 2**

1) **This will not allow you to append in the sense you are wanting**, but you could manually append `-frandom-seed=$(shell md5sum $< | sed 's/\(.*\) .*/\1/')` onto whatever the original value of `CFLAGS` is in the Makefile to get what you want.

2) **The -e option "is not recommended practice"** as stated in the GNU make manual. This is due to the fact that "this would cause different users to get different results from the same makefile"(GNU make Manual).

See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html#Environment) and [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) for more info.